# Simulate double click on a cell in excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel-2007, double-click

Is there any way to simulate double-click on a cell in excel with c#? so the ActiveWorkbook_sheetBeforeDoubleClick event handler will run.

I have used the following code :

```
myActiveSheet.Application.DoubleClick();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Does this help you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b28f493f-0f58-4cdf-ab8c-f4d853a15312

Comment: No,because it describes how to raise double click event in wpf however i need to raise this event for excel sheet.